# gradle exclude group from compile

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting this duplicate error when building my app:

> addJar(...facebookadapter-4.0.3.jar): entry
>   duplicate entry: com/facebook/ads/AbstractAdListener.class

The reason I am getting this is that my app compiles Facebook modules one belongs to an adapter and one to its original SDK:

> compile ('com.ironsource.adapters:facebookadapter:4.0.3@jar')
>   compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.27.0'
>       compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.27.0.0'

So as a solution, I am trying to exclude this group from the module which contains the adapter jar compile statement:

```
compile ('com.ironsource.adapters:facebookadapter:4.0.3@jar') {
    exclude (group: 'com/facebook/ads')
}
```

But, when I build my app again it fails to state the same reason from the same adapter

Any idea why the classes are not being excluded?

Comment: use `gradlew :app:dependencyInsight --configuration compile --dependency com.facebook.ads` to check where the dependency comes from

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the `exclude` block syntax is incorrect. Try

```
compile ('com.ironsource.adapters:facebookadapter:4.0.3@jar') {
  exclude group: 'com.facebook.ads'
}
```

**Update**

So it looks like the `facebookadapter` contains this class inside. You can not exclude a class from a `jar` file, exclusion only works on per-dependency level.

If you absolutely need to have this adapter, you can try to exclude facebook ads transitive dependency from all the other dependencies.

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.facebook.ads'
}
```

Comment: That was my first try, both syntaxes give the same result

Comment: oh, so the class is inside the jar. That makes problem tricker, please see my update

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate on this line "You can not exclude a class from a jar file, exclusion only works on per-dependency level"

Comment: Each dependecy declaration in Gradle defines a subtree:not only the actual library (a single jar file), but all the dependencies of this library as well (transitive dependencies, multiple jar files). The `exclude` directive allows you to exclude some of *transitive dependencies* (exclude several jar files).
In case of `com.ironsource.adapters:facebookadapter:4.0.3@jar` the `com/facebook/ads/AbstractAdListener.class` is a part of library, not a transitive dependency, you can not exclude it this way