# What is the role of 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1' dependency in retrofit 2 when it has its own gson converter?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

```
// Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'

// JSON Parsing
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

My question is regarding the second and third dependency added. I do understand it is related to JSON conversion. If the third dependency is added,would the second dependency still be needed?

I have seen them both being added on several examples. 
For e.g:
https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/sending-data-with-retrofit-2-http-client-for-android--cms-27845

Comment: Its converter role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the [source](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/gson/pom.xml) of Retrofit Gson contverter library, there is a dependency of Gson.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

So, when you include `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson` as your dependency, `com.google.code.gson:gson` will be **automatically included**.

So, you will not need to include the `Gson` dependency explicitly.

Comment: How to exclude gson if it is included in another library?

Comment: @BuffK https://stackoverflow.com/q/48365687/5137352